# Задача про лифт на питоне

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста решить задачу про лифт на Python 3.3.5. (6 кл).
Чтобы поднять на N-й этаж M-этажного дома новый холодильник, Витя вызвал бригаду грузчиков. Оплата работы грузчиков производится так: за подъем холодильника на один этаж требуется заплатить 200 рублей, за спуск на один этаж — 100 рублей. За подъем и спуск на лифте плата не взимается. Несмотря на то, что в Витином доме есть лифт, ему возможно все же придется заплатить грузчикам, поскольку лифт останавливается только на каждом K-м этаже, начиная с первого (то есть на этажах с номерами 1, K+1, 2K+1, 3K+1, …). Требуется вычислить, какой минимальной суммы денег достаточно, чтобы грузчики доставили холодильник с первого этажа на N-й.

Формат входных данных

Во входном файле записаны три числа: M (2≤M≤100), N (2≤N≤M) и K (2≤K≤M–1), разделенные пробелами.

Формат выходных данных

В выходной файл выведите одно число — минимальную стоимость подъема холодильника.

Примеры

Входные данные 20 7 4     20 7 2

Выходные данные 200       0

Вот моя программа. В чем моя ошибка

```
m=int(input())
n=int(input())
k=int(input())
et=1#задан 1-ый этаж
s1=0#обнуление стоймости опускания
s2=0#обнуление стоймости побнятия
if et>m:
    print('нет решения')
else:
    et=et+k
    while et>n:
        s1=(et-n)*100#стоймость опускания
        s2=(n+k-et)*200#стоймость побнятия
    if s1<s2:
        print(s2)
    else:
        print(s1)
```

мой эмеил:andrey.deriabin2012@yandex.ru 
С уважением, Дерябин Андрей 6 кл

Comment: @Андрей Дерябин, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: 1. У вас заданы начальные условия, согласно которым решение есть всегда, а значит лишние проверки не нужны.

2. Если лифт не может довезти до нужного этажа, то грузчикам придется идти q этажей, если лифт остановился ниже нужного этажа, либо K - q, если лифт остановился выше нужного этажа, где q - остаток от деления (N - 1) на K.

3. Может так получиться, что лифт не сможет остановиться выше нужного этажа, т.к. он должен будет остановиться на этаже выше максимального.

4. упс... здесь ошибся, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Про первую проверку уже писал, Дальше:

    while et>n

а у вас где-либо et или n меняется? Я не вижу, поэтому здесь будет бесконечный цикл (если n меньше k), либо цикл не выполнится ни разу (если n больше k). Ни то, ни другое неправильно, нужный алгоритм я описал выше, осталось только реализовать его )

Answer (score 1):

Проверено в 2.7, но на 3-ем тоже будет работать:

```
m = 20
n = 7
k = 4
price_down = 100
price_up = 200

k_list = range(1, m, k)
price = min([price_up*(n - x) if x <= n else (x - n)*price_down for x in k_list])
print price
```

Краткое описание: сначала создаётся список этажей-остановок (`k_list`), затем переходим к вычислению минимальной цены. Вычисляются все варианты цен - внутри квадратных скобок - а потом с помощью `min` определяем наименьшую. Чтобы получить цену из этажа остановки используется условие `x <= n` для определения какую цену использовать (направление вниз-вверх), потом вычисляется количество этажей, которые нужно преодолеть и умножается на соответствующую цену.